# How to detect fractional numbers in image using Firebase ML Kit Text Recognition

Tags: java, android, firebase-mlkit, text-recognition

I am using Firebase's ML Kit Text Recognition in my Android app. It detects plain text from an image quite well but it does not detect fractional numbers such as 1/2. The results I get vary and are unpredictable.

What happens is:

sometimes 1/2 will only detect the last number (2 in this case) so 1/2 --> 2

sometimes 1/2 will be detected as a percent symbol so 1/2 --> %

sometimes 1/2 will be detected as V2 so 1/2 --> V2

Is there a way to detect fractions using Firebase Text Recognizer?

EDIT: It seems to only have a problems with a format like this where numerator is raised and the denominator is lowered between the slash:
[image]

This format seems to be fine where all consecutive characters are at the same level: [image]

Comment: Hi, we made some changes to Firebase ML Kit to better distinguish the on-device APIs from cloud based APIs. "ML Kit"(without firebase branding) contains all the on-device APIs. Here's(https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/migration) the migration guide from firebase mlkit to mlkit.  We are working on upgrading the model used by the text recognizer in the new MLKit. This issue will be solved with new model. Thanks!